# Is asking for a name for one function on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

In [How to name a method that sets some values in a javabean?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4549/1029), the OP only ask for a name of this function, and nothing more. Does it belong to the scope of Code Review?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not great, but I do think it is valid. As someone very much smarter than me once said:

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.

http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2005/12/23/UPI

Comment: Those things weren't even NP-hard those were just "hard"?